# How to know if any of the row contains any value

Tags: php, html, mysql

Let's say I have 3 rows (entries) & 3 columns to display from MySQL DB.

If all "rows" had all "values" in each "columns" then all results will be displayed.
But lets say 1 column has no values in any of the row (entries) then I would not like to display the column itself.

I'm using PHP for this.
Example of my table:

```
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Sex</td>
    <td>Location</td>
</tr>
```

Above code is `thead` of the table. Below this there will be a repeated region displaying values.

So if in DB there is no "Location" entered in any of the records, then I would not to display "Location" `<td>` itself and also in results section.

But if any 1 row contains value in "Location" then it must display in `thead` & in results `tr` as well.

Recordset:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_con1, $con1);
$query_Person = "SELECT * FROM Persons";
$Person = mysql_query($query_Person, $con1) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Person = mysql_fetch_assoc($Person);
$totalRows_Person = mysql_num_rows($Person);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array of the *"Location"* column with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and then check with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).
Assuming your multi-dimensionnal array is called `$data`:

```
$location = array_column($data, 'Location');
$no_location = !array_filter($location);

// For testing
var_dump($no_location);
```

Using `array_filter()` without a callback will remove *falsy* values. As an empty array is also *falsy*, saving the result of the function as a boolean will let you know if this column can be removed.
**Note:** It will return `true` if the *"Location"* column is empty for each row.

Comment: Please have a look at "FYI" in  Question

Comment: getting error as :  Call to undefined function array_column() 
Btw i m using  5.5+ php

Comment: @Sukhwinder `array_column()` works on PHP >= 5.5, you are really encouraged to update your PHP version. And the "FYI" adds nothing, we don't build the HTML for you, I provided a perfectly working answer.

Comment: i m using 5.5+ version.

Comment: What does `echo phpversion()` returns ? It should work.

Comment: Ok i m confused regarding php version . Please find the attached version image details. is mine outdated?

Comment: Yes it says 5.4.31. will update & get back to you. tysm

Comment: @Sukhwinder Reply here to know if it works then. Thanks.

Comment: @AymnDev i have updated it. After my Recordset  i added this : 
$location = array_column($data, 'VariantLength');
$no_location = !array_filter($location);

Notice: Undefined variable: data in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bosch/admin/product-details.php on line 250

Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bosch/admin/product-details.php on line 250

Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bosch/admin/product-details.php on line 251

Comment: @Sukhwinder please make a little effort, the `$data` variable was an example ! Replace it with your results array, `$row_Person` I guess ?

Comment: Ok i was facing issues with my mysql ever since i updated. Now i got a chance to run mysql data. Btw thanks for correcting me. i m not that great with it. Just learning. 
**Coming to the results**
i got the following : bool(true) (I get this result even when value in Location is present or not. how to make it work?)
Now how to show or display a particular td/tr row?

Comment: @Sukhwinder I tested it and it worked, it will output `true` when `"Location"` is empty for every row, and `false` if at least one row has `"Location"` filled. Then build your `<table>`, you know how to make a loop and a condition, don't you ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:-

Suppose you have written a function in your class file to get all records from this table only , then it will say as follows :

```
<?php

$name_stat = 0 ;
$gender_stat = 0 ;
$loc_stat = 0 ;

$get_results = $class_variable->getResults() ;

foreach($get_results as $key=>$val){
    if($val['name'] != ''){
        $name_stat = 1 ;
    }
    if($val['sex'] != ''){
        $gender_stat = 1 ;
    }
    if($val['location'] != ''){
        $loc_stat = 1 ;
    }
}

?>

<tr>
    <?php if($name_stat == 1){?><td>Name</td><?php } ?>
    <?php if($gender_stat == 1){?><td>Sex</td><?php } ?>
    <?php if($loc_stat == 1){?><td>Location</td><?php } ?>
</tr>

<?php

foreach($get_results as $key=>$val){?>

    <tr>
        <?php if($val['name'] != ''){?><td><?=$val['name'];?></td><?php } ?>
        <?php if($val['sex'] != ''){?><td><?=$val['sex'];?></td><?php } ?>
        <?php if($val['location'] != ''){?><td><?=$val['location'];?></td><?php } ?>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Check the above code , it will only display any column if it has at least one value otherwise the heading and content will not occur in the page .

Comment: Please have a look at "FYI" in  Question

Comment: The query section is wrong , please correct the mysql_query , it will be mysql_query($query_Person) and also run a loop , use mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: Correct your query section and use my solution , it will give you the required output .

Comment: is my query wrong? i can display result using <?php echo $row_Person['Location']?>

Please correct me here. my query seems fine.

Comment: Take a while loop and use mysql_fetch_array and put all the records in the html accordingly .